# what do brackets when it is next to an iterative function?

Tags: ruby, brackets

What does `[]` mean when it is next to an iterative function. Not entailing keys and values e.g. `{ |char| count[char] += 1 }`

Comment: What do you mean by _next to an iterative function_? What is an _iterative function_ anyway? The brackets are next to the word `count` in your example. Without knowing the context, `count` can be a function or a variable. If it is a function, it is one which returns as value an object, which understands `[]`(which is nothing special; just a method call). For instance, objects of class `Array` or `Hash` understand `[]`, but you can also write your own class which understands it. Hence, without knowing more of your program, your question can not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

### Some Parts of Block Syntax Explained

`{ |char| count[char] += 1 }` is a *block*. If you're new to Ruby, it may help to think of a block as a sort of anonymous function, but it's actually a language feature that's distinct from Proc and lambda objects. All methods in Ruby implicitly accept a block as their final argument, whether or not they use it.

Inside the block, `|char|` declares the variable that will hold the values passed into the block. Various language features that yield values to blocks will pass their values to the variables so declared.

`count[char]` is just a Hash or Array lookup. It retrieves the value in *count* associated with the key or index in *char*. In your specific example, the value at `count[char]` needs to be an Integer, or the expression will probably raise a TypeError exception.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: `obj[...]` calls the method `[]` on `obj` (with arguments `...`)

---

Your code snippet is probably used to count char occurrences in a string:

```
str = 'hello world'
count = Hash.new(0)
str.each_char { |char| count[char] += 1 }

count
#=> {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>3, "o"=>2, " "=>1, "w"=>1, "r"=>1, "d"=>1}
```

Here, `count` is a hash with a default value of `0`.

Within the block, `char` is one of the string's character, i.e. `"h"`, `"e"`, `"l"` etc.

The brackets are syntactic sugar for a *method call*: [`Hash#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#5B-5D-method) (element reference). But there's another, hidden method call. In Ruby, `a += b` is syntactic sugar for `a = a + b`. So `count[char] += 1` is actually:

```
count[char] = count[char] + 1
```

The left-hand-side being [`Hash#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#5B-5D-3D-method) (element assignment).

Answer (score -1):

[ ] are used to access positions within an array or keys within a hash. in this case you are entering the position char or the corresponding key in this iteration

```
#example
my_array = ['hola', 'chao', 'brb']
my_array[0] #show "hola"

3.times {|x| p my_array[x]} 
#"hola"
#"chao"
#"brb"
#=> 3
```